# Один скрипт для нескольких элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код:

```
        div id="clockdiv">
                <div>
                    <span class="days"></span>
                    <div class="smalltext">дня</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="hours"></span>
                    <div class="smalltext">часа</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="minutes"></span>
                    <div class="smalltext">минут</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="seconds"></span>
                    <div class="smalltext">секунд</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

И JS код:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 31 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var deadline = 'December 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+02:00';
var deadline = 'August 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+02:00';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Необходимо добавить на страницу аналогичный таймер с отчетом, но при добавлении работает только один, как можно исправить ? Если не сложно, то подскажите вариант для таймера с разными отчетами.

Comment: придумайте аналогичному таймеру другой id и добавьте в js строчку `initializeClock('придуманный id', deadline);`

Comment: ага. https://jsfiddle.net/r1tmrya7/

Comment: @SvArt713  посмотрите по ссылке. там же все работает